# macOS python3 with brew, error on import cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy, opencv

I installed python3 in my macOS through brew, 
I installed opencv and numpy, 
when I import cv2 and numpy I have this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "001.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 79, in bootstrap
    import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: Could you provide the commands used to install the packages and the path of `pip`, `conda`, `python` you are using? Probably some packages have been installed using system's packet manager and python runtime is from homebrew or the way around. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the problem in this way:

- I installed opencv using brew

`brew install opencv`

- I installed opencv for python

`pip install opencv-python`

- I removed (bad) numpy library

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy`

- I linked numpy library with working library

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy`